# Retrieve multiple columns from DataTable and return a DataTable using LINQ C#

Tags: c#, linq

Table: tblCustomer columns: custId(string), custFName(string), custLName(string), Address1(string), Address2(string), City(String),
Zipcode(string), State(String), email(string), Phone(string).

I want to retrieve the values of these columns: custId(string), custFName(string), custLName(string), email(string), Phone(string) from tblCustomer.

I want to change the column names to Customer Id, First Name, Last Name, Email, Phone Number in the new table.

I am able to get only one column. How to get multiple columns and all rows and convert it to a DataTable

```
DataTable dt = tblCustomer
   .AsEnumerable()
   .Select(rows => rows.Field<string>("custId").Copytodatatable()
```

Comment: You can't using linq.  CopyToDataTable will only filter rows, not columns.  Either you can copy entire table to new table and then delete column you do not want.  Or create a new table with column you want and then move data from original table to new table in a for loop, not with linq.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call the [`.ToTable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.dataview.totable?view=netframework-4.8&f1url=%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Data.DataView.ToTable)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework%2CVersion%253Dv4.8)%3Bk(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue) method of the [`DataTable.DefaultView`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datatable.defaultview?view=netframework-4.8&f1url=%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Data.DataTable.DefaultView)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework%2CVersion%253Dv4.8)%3Bk(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue) property and pass the columns in question.

```cs
var cols = new[] { "custId", "custFName", "custLName", "email", "Phone" };
var dt = tblCustomer.DefaultView.ToTable(false, cols);
```

Or

```cs
var dt = tblCustomer.DefaultView.ToTable(false, 
    "custId", "custFName", "custLName", "email", "Phone");
```

To *name* the new `DataTable`, use an overload that takes the `tableName` param.

```cs
var dt = tblCustomer.DefaultView.ToTable("Customer", false, 
    "custId", "custFName", "custLName", "email", "Phone");
```

To *rename* the column captions, assign new caption to the [`DataColumn.Caption`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datacolumn.caption?view=net-6.0) property of each column.

```cs
var dt = tblCustomer.DefaultView.ToTable("Customer", false, 
    "custId", "custFName", "custLName", "email", "Phone");

dt.Columns["custId"].Caption = "Customer Id";
dt.Columns["custFName"].Caption = "First Name";
dt.Columns["custLName"].Caption = "Last Name";
// ...etc.
```

Comment: dr.null, Thanks for the response. I want to change the column names to Customer Id, First Name, Last Name, Email, Phone Number in the new table.

Comment: @Buddy26 You're welcome. See the revision.

Comment: dr.null, Thanks for your response. But the GridView is looking for the columns Customer Id, First Name, Last Name etc.. Captions aren't helping. But ColumnName is working.

Comment: dt.Columns["custId"].ColumnName = "Customer Id";

Comment: @Buddy26 Very well then. There was a bug in the first code block here due to the copy/paste. `var dt = tblCustomer = tblCustomer....` is a mistake. Please be aware of that to not modify the source `DataTable`.